# How to run ruby with sublime text ON GOOGLE CHROME

Tags: html, ruby, google-chrome

I can't find anyway to have this code run properly:

```
my_num = 4*100, puts "my_num"
```

The only way I can run code with sublime (my only option) is running the code on chrome, but when I do, it just shows the code. How can I attach this to HTML so it will run properly? Is there any other option?

Comment: Why don't you run it via the terminal. Or is the code an `html.erb file`

Comment: Do you want this code in HTML? Is this all you have in the file?

Comment: this is all i have, but how do I run it in terminal? (like, specific code that I can use.)

Comment: In sublime text, just type `Ctrl+B` or in terminal, type `ruby myfile.rb`. Also make sure you have ruby installed on your machine and the path is added to environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Sublime has a feature built in to allow this without even leaving your text editor.

Click on Tools, then Build With, then select Ruby.

Now simply click on Tools again, and now Build. A new section will open at the bottom, giving you the output of your ruby code.

For example:

```
puts 'Hello World!'
```

and then running build, gives a new window at the bottom with the output

```
Hello World!
```

EDIT: You also asked how to run it in terminal, you would need to save the file, and then run it from terminal. Say you saved it in

```
/projects/test.rb
```

then you can run it from terminal by either typing in:

```
ruby projects/test.rb
```

or switching into your projects directory, and then just running

```
ruby test.rb
```

Comment: This was what I had put in:                                                                        (start)Last login: Fri May 19 09:54:14 on ttys000
-bash: Hello, AND DO YOUR HOMEWORK!: command not found
Sarah-Herberts-MacBook-Pro:~ Lukecat2883$ ruby

ruby frigYearTwo.rb(end)                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                  
what do I do to run it?

Comment: You're not picking out the file properly. Go into your finder and see exactly where in your file tree it is stored, then navigate to that directory in terminal and type in ruby frigYearTwo.rb. You can see what is in your current directory by typing in 'ls' without the quotes - if you don't see your ruby file you're in the wrong directory

Comment: it's on my desktop. Do i need to set it to /desktop/frigYearTwo.rb?

Comment: It's more likely going to be users/mark/Desktop where mark is your username. If you're struggling, open up file explorer / finder and it will show you the path at the bottom (it should look something like users/mark/Desktop)

Comment: OK so ignore my last comment - open up terminal - type in 'cd ~/desktop' without quotes and then type in 'ruby frigYearTwo.rb' again without quotes

Comment: So, I got that. but how do i get it to show me the output?

Comment: It does so. And for what it's worth, your original file needs to be on 2 separate lines without quotes:
my_num = 4*100
puts my_num

Comment: When I run that ruby file from terminal, it prints out '400'

Comment: for me, no matter what I press, nothing happens. at all. I cant get anything to work except to print the same line over an over again.

Comment: What is it outputting at the moment?

Comment: Sarah-Herberts-MacBook-Pro:~ Lukecat2883$

Comment: OK final solution (pardon the term) - open the file in sublime - click on tools --> 'Build with' and select ruby, then click on tools --> build.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some websites which can interpret ruby, the browser itself does not run the language. However Ruby has a lot of tools for building HTML pages. For example to display your result in the browser, you can take use [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) (embedded ruby) which ships with ruby.

Given this file at `foo.html.erb`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <%= 4 * 100 %>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can compile the ERB tag (`<%= %>`) to HTML with `erb foo.html.erb > foo.html`. Then open foo.html in the browser. It will display "400" and nothing else.